# Java JXBrowser: Is it possible to draw over the JXBrowser Component?

Tags: java, graphics, paint, paintcomponent, jxbrowser

I just wanted to know if it's possible to paint over the JXBrowser component? I have searched on the internet and found that the used BrowserView inherits paintcomponents etc. But I can't seem to get it to work.

Here's the code:

```
        public test() {
    browser = new Browser();
    view = new BrowserView(browser);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    panel.add(view, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    test = new JButton("Open FOE");
    test.addActionListener(this);
    test1 = new JButton("Helpen");
    test1.addActionListener(this);
    test1.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(90, 20));
    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel1, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    panel1.add(test);
    panel1.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 15)));
    panel1.add(test1);

    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    panel2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    panel2.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    panel2.add(panel1, BorderLayout.EAST);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(panel2);
    frame.setSize(1500, 1000);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

How it looks now:

[image: First]

What I want to achieve: 
[image: Second]

Comment: mount a glass pane on top of the frame and draw whatever you want.

Comment: I have never worked with glass pane's. Will it go over the BrowserView? Wont it fuck up the browser?

Comment: if you use it in right way, it should work.

Comment: Could you give me an example where you draw over another component with the glass pane?

Comment: since code sample cannot be added as a comment , i added it as a answer

Answer (score 0):

Use glass pane,
sample code fragment:

```
JPanel glassPane = new JPanel()
    {
      @Override
      protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
      {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawString("Test",100,100);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.drawRect(300,300,300,300);
      }
    };

    glassPane.setOpaque(false);   
    frame.getGlassPane().setVisible(true);

    frame.setGlassPane(glassPane);
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Thank you I will try when I come home

Comment: just replace your last line with these code fragment and test it

Comment: I did what you said but the blue rectangle draws under the webbrowser. When i start the application i see the blue rects for a second and then the browser appears and the blue rects is gone.

Comment: i havent used JXbroser, so it might be a heavyweight component then, probably you popup menu also will be hidden under this JXBrowser, i have one suggestion create a new class which is subclass of Browser, and override the  paint(Graphics g) method and call super.paint method and after that try to draw something.

Comment: I will try that, like test class extends Browser etc..?

Comment: JxBrowser supports two rendering modes: heavyweight (default) and lightweight. In your case you need to configure it to use the lightweight rendering mode to avoid this overlapping issue: https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000013069-lightweight-or-heavyweight